# iOS Mail Composer Won't Dismiss

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, email

I am trying to take a screenshot and email it using the mail composer.  Everything works great except the mail composer won't dismiss. This post seems to have the same problem, but the solution provided did not work for me. [Can't dismiss the email composer view in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530283/cannot-dismiss-the-email-composer-view-in-iphone)

```
- (IBAction)Email:(id)sender {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
    MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    mailComposer.delegate = self;
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Risk Assessment"];
    [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];     
    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];        
}
}
```

The above code works great. How do I call this bottom portion.  It seems like the compiler just skips past it.

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
if (error){
    NSString *errorTitle = @"Mail Error";
    NSString *errorDescription = [error localizedDescription];
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:errorTitle message:errorDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [errorView show];                
    [errorView release];
}
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

instead of

```
mailComposer.delegate = self;
```

From the [MFMailComposeViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> mailComposeDelegate;
```

> The delegate object is responsible for dismissing the view presented by this view controller at the appropriate time. Therefore, you should always provide a delegate and that object should implement the methods of the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that last line should be

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The ViewController that presented the view modally, also dismisses it.

Comment: That's right, the way he wrote it should work too, but the preferred way is the one you described [Apple Docs on Dismissing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14)